# databinding only executes once on a two-way bound model

Tags: android

I have the following `EditText` layout.

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@{ android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(account.email).matches()? com.mdsf.R.style.MNS_TextAppearance_Hint : com.mdsf.R.style.MNS_TextAppearance_Hint_Error}"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="@{android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(account.email).matches()? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@={account.email}"
                style="@style/MnsEditText"
                android:hint="Email"/>
```

My issue is that the databinidng for `hintTextAppearance` does not reexecute when changes to `account.email` are made via the double binding. I have confirmed that the account's `email` property is being updated by the `EditText` text property. Here is my account model and here is the Activity as well:

```
public class Account extends BaseObservable {

public int id;
public int mediaId;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String email ="";
public String password;
public String addressLine1;
public String addressLine2;
public String city;
public String region;
public String phone;
public String gender;
public String postalCode;

public boolean isSetUp;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Bindable
public int getMediaId() {
    return mediaId;
}

public void setMediaId(int mediaId) {
    this.mediaId = mediaId;
}

@Bindable
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Bindable
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Bindable
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

I set a breakpoint and i see that `getEmail` is never called while adding or changing the text bound to `account.email`.

Finally here is my `<data>` tag at the beginning of my layout resource:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="account"
        type="com.msdf.network.model.Account" />
 </data>
```

And finally my `Account` activity

```
public class CreateAccountActivity extends BaseTabBarActivity {
private Account account;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityCreateAccountBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_create_account);
    account = new Account();
    //account.setEmail("gig@c.com");
    binding.setAccount(account);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem, after reading [this excellent resource](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-observability-9de4ff3fe038), was solved after I realized I had omitted a very essential part of the DataBinding setup. Namely, for the setter of the `account.email` property I had failed to write

```
public void setEmail(String email){
  this.email = email;
  notifiyPropertyChanged(BR.email); //This line was omitted
}
```

Thus even though the two way binding was working for my TextEditField, it wasn't notifying the model that `email` had changed thus anything binding to `account.email` got no update that it had changed, even though it was successfully written to.